# How to define is object has activities enabled via REST API?

Tags: rest

Is it possible to figure out if activities enabled for particular object via REST?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there is no direct way to get this information by Rest API.

But when `Allow Activities` option is enabled for a custom object, following gets added to SObject describe:

1. `LastActivityDate` field on object.
2. `ActivityHistory` and `OpenActivity` on child relationship.

You could use these to know if the feature is enabled.

---

Describe SObject URL:

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/{Object API Name}/describe
```

Answer (score 1):

That information is not exposed in Rest API or Partner API. You need to use Metadata Soap API to read metadata for that object.

In Metadata API this is exposed as field `CustomObject.enableActivities` field. See [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) reference for more info.

Comment: Nice. I was also looking at metadata API first but didn't find it. Thanks for sharing!